# Textbox in footer not expanding dynamically with page width in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

I'm having issues getting a text-box in the footer to grow dynamically with the page width. I have tried setting the horizontal align on the textbox to right aligned but it hasn't helped.

Comment: Are you having an issue with the 'page number' extending too far or the 'executed on' section not extending?

Comment: I'm having issue with the page number not extending with the page width. As you can see, the page number is right in the middle of the page instead of being far right along with the page growth.